# OkHttp thread priority background on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, okhttp

On Android is recommended to set thread priority to `THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` to avoid that other threads interfere with the main thread.
OkHttp uses multiple thread pools (dispatcher, connectionpool etc) but i see that it doesn't worry about thread priority. As an example Google Volley library in [NetworkDispatcher#84](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/NetworkDispatcher.java#84) uses `THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`

Is there a reason for OkHttp to not set thread priorities? When using it on Android should i replace the thread factory with one that set thread priority to background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the thread priority to whatever you like, using the APIs offered for the executor service, etc.

For the most part, OkHttp doesn't use the CPU, and when it does I typically don't want it to be low priority. OkHttp spends its initial CPU cycles preparing to send your network request. I like getting the network I/O underway as urgently as possible because that gets your response back as urgently as possible. Once the request is away, OkHttp doesn't use the CPU. It just blocks, quietly awaiting the network response. Finally when that returns I like to get that back to the caller urgently.

TL;DR: You can help yourself to tweak thread priorities, but it won't make much difference because OkHttp doesn't use the CPU much, and when it does use the CPU I think it's often a good idea to get the I/O started as soon as possible.